# Карта со своими отметками

Tags: php, javascript, карты

Здравствуйте. В данный момент пишу сервис с каталогом вечеринок. При создании вечеринки нужно указывать отметку на карте города. Так же на одной странице будет карта со всеми созданными отметками. Не подскажете, какую карту использовать? Ну и может уже есть готовые решения? Вообщем надеюсь на максимальную информацию по данному вопросу.

Comment: эта возможность есть и на яндексе и на гугле, выбирайте, что для Вас лучше.

Comment: Я бы посоветовала использовать библиотеку для работы с картами Leaflet http://leafletjs.com/ Простая, понятная, ничего лишнего, при необходимости можно подключить плагины.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте Open Street Map, это мощный инструмент. У них есть API. Вот о них [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/270513/) . А так же вроде у "Яндекс-Карт" есть JavaScript API(но не знаю, хватит ли вам его)

Comment: Для того чтобы создавать метки на карте, совсем не надо использовать геоданные, про которые приведенная вам статья.

Comment: В приведенной мной статье есть информация как добавлять в принципе точки на карту, а отобразить их можно уже по разному(и в Yandex и Гугл картах)